# How do I prevent "Contents" from appearing twice in the header when I use \leftmark and \rightmark with fancyhdr?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr

I would like to use `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`, but have "Contents" appear only once (on the left) in the header. Instead, it appears as both the `\leftmark` and the `\rightmark`.

The following MWE illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\rightmark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you have at least one `\section` command in the same page of your ToC, the problem disappears.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Yes. Unfortunately the ToC takes up a full page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the definition of `\tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\rightmark}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
%           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}% DELETED
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{}}% ADDED
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    } 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. How would I make it appear only on the right?

Comment: @Will By removing the first `\MakeUppercase\contentsname` from the definition instead of the second one.

Comment: @Will Note, however, that `\tableofcontents` is considered a section in the `article` class, and therefore *should* change `\leftmark`. Wether it should change `\rightmark` too is more debatable.

Answer (score 8):

The user guide to the `fancyhdr` package notes on p. 10 that

> It should be noted that the LATEX marking mechanism works fine with chapters (which always start on a new page) and sections which are reasonably long. It does not work quite as well with short sections and subsections. This is a problem with LATEX, not with fancyhdr.

AFAICT, an easy workaround, which doesn't require the redefinition of LaTeX's `\tableofcontents` command, consists of specifying `\rhead{}` before the `\tableofcontents` command, followed by `\rhead{\rightmark}` before the first section:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\begin{document}
\rhead{}   % set \rhead to empty
\tableofcontents

\clearpage   % OP has indicated that ToC spans a full page
\rhead{\rightmark} % reset \rhead to \rightmark

\section{Hello}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer customization in the preamble, but +1 for the `fancyhdr` quote.

Comment: Is there a way to handle this for the `book` class? The markings would then need to alternate with even/odd pages.

Comment: @rubenvb - May I suggest that you pose this query as a new question? That way, it'll get far more visibility. :-)

Comment: @Mico will do :-)

Answer (score 2):

`\rightmark` uses the first right mark of the page. So you can also set before `\tableofcontents` an empty `\markright` to get rid of the right mark on the first page and use an `addtocontents` to insert a `\markright` in the toc to get rid of the right mark on the following pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\begin{document}
\markright{}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\markright{}}
%some text in the toc for test:
\addtocontents{toc}{blub}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\newpage}
\addtocontents{toc}{blub}

\end{document}
```

Btw: You are not saying which informations `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` will contain. You should be aware that some combinations (e.g. section/subsection) can led to confusing results. As a thumb of rule the `\leftmark` should be connected to something that starts a new page, like a `\part` or a `\chapter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

\rhead[]{Contents}

\lhead[Contents]{}

\tableofcontents

\markboth{}{\rm Contents}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is the most simple way to deal with such problem. Thanks

Comment: Who are you thanking to?